# Why cant I get clear wave?

Tags: oscilloscope, stepper-motor, sine, stepper-driver

I'm trying to find a good stepper driver with low vibrations and low noise. So, I observed wave form between current sensing resistor of few stepper driver using my oscilloscope. 
The voltage between current sensing resistor is proportional to current of the motor phase. Because of that I should be able to observe a wave form shape like as describe in the datasheet without negative half.( I can observe that negative half as positive half.because of there is no current direction change in the resistor)

When I observed the wave for I got like below,
[image: TB6600HQ wave form]

Described wave form in the datasheet,
[image: Described wave form in the datasheet]

This is different from wave form shown in datasheet. Micro-stepping is perfectly work(Green is step pulse and yellow is current sensing resistor voltage)

Hope you can understand my observations. My question is why can't I get waveform as datasheet. I got a same as datasheet using another stepper driver that has [TA8435HQ](https://www.terraelectronica.ru/pdf/show?pdf_file=%2Fz%2FDatasheet%2FT%2FTA8435HQ.pdf). But, Using [TB6600](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=14683&prodName=TB6600HG) I couldn't get the clear wave form as datasheet.

Comment: [Pulse-Width Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)

Comment: @brhans I cant understand your point? Can you explain something

Comment: PWM is what your stepper driver is doing to produce that stepped waveform. Zoom your 'scope in and you'll see it.

Comment: Yes. I know that. my question is Why cant I get wave form as shown in datasheet?

Comment: perhaps you are not using the oscilloscope correctly ...... connect the "green" probe to the "yellow" signal ..... leave "yellow" probe disconnected ..... what do you see?

Comment: The diagram in the datasheet IS NOT a waveform you can see on an oscilloscope. Since the current level is achieved by switching drive on and off  (the current resistors provide the current level detection) rapidly what you see is the current pulses defined by the chopper.

Comment: Is your scope on single-trace? If not, try that.

Comment: @JackCreasey I have previously observed same wave form as datasheet. That driver used TA8435HQ. But, I can only see positive half of the signal and It has some noises. But, almost same as datasheet.

Comment: @jsotola I have used oscilloscope correctly. I tried with different stepper driver also. TB6600 and M524 stepper driver also.

Comment: @user_fs10. The datasheet does not show the chopper in action, only the target current level for the driver. The oscilloscope trace you show is correct for a correctly functioning chopper.

Comment: @JackCreasey Pls look at the below link. Its the TA8435 wave form between current sensing resistor. It clearly shows current step according to datasheet. Why cant I get like this wave form when using TB6600
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JcEzVJK3sGjkkitRvjFPIRQ-Ktuha6da/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's to do with the value of the coil inductance and the frequency of the clock used for the chopper. The waveform you show clearly shows the inductor current does not get close to zero. If you altered the clock osc on the TB6600 you could get the same waveform. But the waveform can NEVER look like the graphic shown in the datasheets for any chopper regulated device.

Comment: @JackCreasey Yes. This is not the same wave form as shown in datasheet. But, Why can't I get like this wave form using TB6600 ? 
If I change clock osc, How can I get this? clock osc is responsible for chopping frequency. any of chopping frequency should make a wave form like TA8435 as I think.

Comment: As I said you can get it the same, but you'd have to change the osc frequency. Di you read my comment??